# Shader problem after mirror modifier

Tags: shaders, mirror-modifier

After adding mirror modifier the other part of the chair leg has some shading problem.
I have tried :

1. check face orientation
   2.recalculate normals

Please help.

Shade smooth :[image: Shade smooth]

Shade flat :[image: shade flat]

Wireframe :[image]

Face normal : [image]
Blend file : https://pasteall.org/blend/eb989c31e7494803b4c9896fd88533b9

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Added in question. Sorry, should have attached while posting question.

Comment: I don't see the same problem on my own computer but maybe apply the scale and in the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > click on Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Comment: @moonboots Applying scale solved the problem. (Custom split normal is required for my model, So I did not cleared it). Please add it as an answer, I will close this question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is stretched a lot. Apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your object normals are correct. To do this, select the whole object in edit mode and press shift + n.

Also check the geometric data of the object through the object data properties section and delete this section if there is any information

Comment: Object normals are correct, I have checked face orientation, and also recalculated normals. BTW applying scal solved the problem.